# What is irc.ubuntu.com used for?

Tags: community, irc

IRC channels are one of the most significant parts of Ubuntu community infrastructure. However, all Ubuntu channels I've ever met are hosted on **irc.freenode.net**. What's the point of **irc.ubuntu.com**? I've seen some users claiming they can be found there... But is that server used at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

irc.freenode.com and irc.ubuntu.com refer to the same collection of irc servers. They are both CNAMEs (DNS aliases) for chat.freenode.net. The current setup is as following

```
andreas@stilgar:~$ host irc.freenode.com
irc.freenode.com is an alias for chat.freenode.com.
chat.freenode.com is an alias for chat.freenode.net.
chat.freenode.net has address 93.152.160.101
chat.freenode.net has address 82.96.64.4
chat.freenode.net has address 208.82.117.76
chat.freenode.net has address 213.92.8.4
chat.freenode.net has address 213.232.93.3
chat.freenode.net has address 130.239.18.172
chat.freenode.net has address 38.229.70.20
chat.freenode.net has address 84.240.3.129
chat.freenode.net has address 89.16.176.16
chat.freenode.net has address 130.237.188.200
chat.freenode.net has address 94.125.182.252
chat.freenode.net has address 50.22.136.18
chat.freenode.net has address 78.40.125.4
chat.freenode.net has address 140.211.167.98
chat.freenode.net has address 140.211.167.99
chat.freenode.net has address 216.155.130.130
chat.freenode.net has address 86.65.39.15
chat.freenode.net has address 213.179.58.83
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:19f0:feee::dead:beef:cafe
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2a03:280:0:1::1
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:1418:13:1::25
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2a02:2498:3a3:1b96::1
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:820:2::6
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:6b0:5:1688::200
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:6b0:e:2018::172
andreas@stilgar:~$ host irc.ubuntu.com
irc.ubuntu.com is an alias for chat.freenode.net.
chat.freenode.net has address 213.232.93.3
chat.freenode.net has address 94.125.182.252
chat.freenode.net has address 140.211.167.98
chat.freenode.net has address 208.82.117.76
chat.freenode.net has address 216.155.130.130
chat.freenode.net has address 78.40.125.4
chat.freenode.net has address 140.211.167.99
chat.freenode.net has address 50.22.136.18
chat.freenode.net has address 213.92.8.4
chat.freenode.net has address 130.237.188.200
chat.freenode.net has address 84.240.3.129
chat.freenode.net has address 89.16.176.16
chat.freenode.net has address 82.96.64.4
chat.freenode.net has address 213.179.58.83
chat.freenode.net has address 86.65.39.15
chat.freenode.net has address 130.239.18.172
chat.freenode.net has address 38.229.70.20
chat.freenode.net has address 93.152.160.101
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2a02:2498:3a3:1b96::1
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:6b0:e:2018::172
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:6b0:5:1688::200
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:19f0:feee::dead:beef:cafe
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:820:2::6
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2001:1418:13:1::25
chat.freenode.net has IPv6 address 2a03:280:0:1::1
andreas@stilgar:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

As given on [Ubuntu IRC channels](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat)
There are several Internet relay chat (IRC) channels on the freenode network (irc.freenode.net) used for Ubuntu support and development.

The best place to start for general help with Ubuntu or just to meet other Ubuntu users is #ubuntu or one of the many local language channels.

Specific channels are available for Ubuntu derivatives: #kubuntu, #edubuntu, #lubuntu and #xubuntu and separate channels relate to development, bugs, local community (LoCo) teams, accessibility and documentation. Choose from the current list of channels .
hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but although your answer explains well what IRC channels are used for, it is related to **irc.freenode.net**, and do not answer my question, which concerns **irc.ubuntu.com**

Comment: they both are the same as stated in the answer below `irc.freenode.com is an alias for chat.freenode.com.`  `irc.ubuntu.com is an alias for chat.freenode.net.`